# how to do comparision against a field with specified split character?

Tags: mysql

Here is the scenario:

```
id  |   vals
1   |   123#45
```

At first, I intended to use

```
select * from `a_table` where `val` REGEXP "45"
```

to do the match. But then I realized that if I pass `val REGEXP "23"`, it would falsely match the record with `id`=1. Some here's the problem:

How can I match the keyword in field `vals`, which is splitted by character '#' without any false match like above? Thanks a lot!

Comment: First rule, normalize your table one more step.

Comment: or at least use comma as the separator, so you can use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter -

```
SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE val REGEXP '^(45#)|(#45#)|(#45)$'
```